# What would be a good optimization technique for this kind of problem?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, constrained-optimization, particle-swarm-optimization

## Problem Description:

Since I am not sure if there is a scientific term that categorizes this problem, I will do my best to describe it thoroughly.
Suppose there is a chamber that's being filled with poisonous gas. The amount of poisonous gas being released at 1-second intervals can be represented as a time series such as:
[image]

In order to reduce the poisonous gas, the operator has access to a set of jobs, which if initiated at a certain time, can release a certain amount of neutralizing gas per second over a certain duration. Specifically, a job can be represented as $$J_i(amount_i, duration_i, cooldown_i)$$ where:

- $amount_i$ is the amount of neutralizing gas released by $J_i$ per second
- $duration_i$ is how long $J_i$ lasts when activated
- $cooldown_i$ is how long $J_i$ is unavailable before it can be used again. **Note that this property is what makes this optimization problem difficult** (more on that later).

Note that in this particular problem, at any timestamp $t$, the neutralizing gas can only reduce the poisonous gas that is present at timestamp $t$. So in other words, it doesn't linger.

**$Problem_1$:** **If the operator has access to a set of jobs $J = ({J_0, J_1, J_2, ...})$, what would be the best placements of jobs in order to end up with the least total amount of poisonous gas remaining in the chamber?**

There are many possible solutions, but a good one would have to allocate a job with the right amount at the right time. Because remember if a high-throughput job is allocated when there is hardly any poisonous gas being released, then it would all go to waste. The cooldowns are also a big factor since the assignments would have consequences on the entire timeline. Hence, I reckoned this might be a good optimization candidate for AI.

An example of a solution can be shown as:
[image]

What makes this problem difficult is the cooldown constraint for every job. Because the constraint is not on the range of values, but rather on the different possible solutions. What I mean is that if the optimization algorithm comes up with a potential solution that uses $J_0$ at timestamp $t$, it somehow needs to understand that it should ignore any other solution that tries to use $J_0$ between timestamps $t$ and $t + cooldown_0$. I assume the optimization algorithm that is useful for the problem should be somehow capable of that.

### Question:

**What would be a good optimization technique to solve (or approximate) $Problem_1$ given its jobs' cooldown constraint?**

## More info (what I have tried):

- **PSO:** I was hoping to use Particle Swarm Optimization, but the issues are:

  - **High number of dimensions:** To be able to map job assignments to particles, the number of dimensions blows up to `number of jobs * total_duration_seconds`. So for example for 15 different jobs over 6 minutes, it would result in 5400 particle dimensions, where each dimension can be either 0 or 1. So for example, if `particle_dimensions[3]` is 1 then it represents using the 1st job ($J_0$) at timestamp = 4 seconds. Similarly if `particle_dimensions[360 + 5]` is 1, then it represents using the 2nd job ($J_1$) at timestamp = 6 seconds.  Is there a better way of mapping the particles so that the number of dimensions are lower?
  - **Job cooldown:** more importantly, the cooldown constraint makes the search space full of unfeasible areas which makes finding feasible solutions very difficult. Because if $J_0$ is used at 4 seconds, represented by $particle\_dimensions[3] = 1$ then only at index $particle\_dimensions[3 + cooldown_0]$ and later the value can be 1 again. All the values in between must be 0, otherwise, it would violate the cooldown constraint for $J_0$. Now imagine this must be held true for all jobs, so the whole 5400 dimensions need to be set in a way that none of them violate the cooldowns of each job respectively. In order to tackle this, I have assigned a penalty to unfeasible solutions, but they are so many that the particles cannot find their way into the few (very spread-apart) feasible areas. **Is this why using PSO is a bad idea here? Or is there a way to tell particles how they should move in order to respect the cooldown constraint for each and every job? Is that even possible?**
- **Constrained Programming:** I am not very familiar with this paradigm, but it seems interesting given the cooldown constraint. Do you think this would be a good approach to tackle the cooldown constraint?